# Adding a comment link to the top of every post

Tags: comments

By default, all of the posts on our Wordpress install have a post comment link at the bottom of the post.  How can we add one at the top?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`comments_link()` template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_link), anywhere in your template (but within the Loop) that you need to display a link to the post comments.